# How to track user when redirecting through different pages

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have currently made a website with a login page and a home page(with nodejs, js and html)(client side will send the entered user name and pass to server, when its checked the server will send a reply, based on which the client side redirects to the home page). When redirecting a user from one page to another how can the server track which user is connected on the client side when navigating through different pages ?

Edit:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GihQAC1I39Q&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified
After reading the replies and googling about it, reached this video which was exactly what i needed.

Comment: that usually happens via cookies

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking

If your page uses redirects, the redirecting page becomes the landing page's referrer. For example, if you've changed your site so that index.html now redirects to home.html, then index.html becomes the referrer for home.html. If someone reached your site via a Google search that sent them first to index.html, you won't have any data regarding the Google search.

For this reason, you should place the Google Analytics tracking code on the redirecting page as well as on the landing page. This way, the redirecting page will capture the actual referrer information for your reports.

Note, some browsers may actually redirect before the JavaScript call from the code can be made.
(cf. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009614?hl=en)

Comment: The google analytics tracking code was one of the option i looked on, but seemed kind of unnecessary for the application im working. But i did think of using it for another project i had in mind.